# Using StringFormat in xaml binding with textblock

Tags: wpf, binding, string-formatting

I have the following xaml:

```
<Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name, StringFormat='&quot;{0}&quot;'}" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />

...

<Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name, StringFormat='&lt;{0}&gt;'}" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />

...

<Setter Property="Text">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Binding Path="Name" StringFormat="&quot;{0}&quot;" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
```

The value of Name is displayed in the correct colour so I know the setters are working but the <, > and " never appear. Is there something I'm missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Kieran

Comment: I just tried exactly that in my current Silverlight-application and that worked like a charm...

Comment: I'm using WPF VS2010, do you think that should make a difference?

Comment: I don't think that it _should_ make a difference, but I do think it _could_ make a difference ;)

Comment: Sorry, I found that I was binding to the text in the <TextBlock> node and so the binding in the trigger wasn't working, when I took this out it worked fine. Thanks anyway